# How can I copy conditional formatting cells from Excel to Word?

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have tried to copy cells formatted with conditional formula from Excel to Word and only the text is copied. When copy-pasting the format is lost in word.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy your range in excel
2. In Word, under the `Home` tab, click the down arrow under `Paste` (or right click) and
3. Under `Paste Options`, select `Keep Source Formatting (K)`